# Apply box-shadow on div if border exist

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to add a `box-shadow` to all divs ONLY IF they already have a border.
A lot of div are just used for positioning.

```
div{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 2pt black;
}
```

is of course too much. I was thinking of this, but i can't find the correct syntax :

```
div[style*="border-width:1px;"]{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 2pt black;
}
```

The code i'm looking for shoudln't target a specific page or structure. It's a custom userstyle for every pages.

Comment: That will only work if you have inline styles

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Another idea ?

Comment: How are the borders being added in the first place? Are you not able to create rules for the `box-shadow` based on existing CSS rules that apply the borders?

Comment: I'm making a custom userstyle for browser. I have no control on the rest of the css.

Comment: If the question is "can a style be applied based on the existence of another style, using purely CSS", unfortunately the answer is no.

Comment: _Another idea?_ ... if non inline style is used you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a pure CSS way of doing this, however I have managed to get a jQuery solution if that's any good to you.

The button is just to demonstrate the before and after. Im assuming in your real project you would want to do this on document ready.

```js
$('#shadowMeUp').click(function(){
  $("div")
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('border-style') == "solid"
    })
    .addClass("shadow");
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.border_box {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: indianred;
  border-style: solid;
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="shadowMeUp">Add shadows</button>

<br>

<div class="box border_box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box border_box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no pure CSS solution for this one...

As mentioned, you can use javascript to detect which elements have `border`, and then apply to them your custom box-shadow, but this would be a pretty bad practice, and can potentially carry a big performance cost on your page.